# How to run only a specific period of simulation in veins,omnet?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I want to run LuSTScenario with veins,omnet,but the scenario is too big that the simulation runs very slowly. So it may cost one day or more to run a complete simulation.Is there any way to work smart and run only a specific period of simulation,such as 8:00AM-9:00AM,4:00PM-5:00PM?

Comment: Is this question answered?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can ideed limit the simulation interval by using the following two parameters:

1. `firstStepAt` from the TraCIScenarioManager to define the beginning of the simulation. Thus, Veins will only simulate vehicles starting from this point.
2. `sim-time-limit` from OMNeT++ to define the end of the simulation.

Example (8:00 a.m. to 9:00 a.m.):

```
*.manager.firstStepAt = 28800s # 8:00 a.m.
sim-time-limit = 32400s # 9:00 a.m.
```

A few more hints for coping with a slow simulation:

1. Compile your code in release mode
2. Use `Cmdenv` as runtime environment (`./run -u Cmdenv`)